# How is c# reflection a runtime event?

Tags: c#, reflection, rtti

Every definition says C# reflections is used to determine type of object in runtime. Can the type of an object change in runtime? Can anybody please provide me an example.

Comment: `void Foo(object o) => Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());` -- the compile-time type of `o` is `object`, but you can pass in a `string`, `int`, or anything else at runtime

Comment: small clarification - when you say "runtime event", bear in mind that we are not talking about "events" (encapsulated delegates), but rather as "something that happens in runtime".

Answer (score 2):

Of course an entity can change its **runtime** type during runtime. It just can't change its **compile** type. This is because c# is a type safe language (once a given type, always a given type).

Suppose you have 3 classes - one an abstract class say `Animal` and two classes that derive from it, say `Cat` and `Dog`. Then

```
Animal animal = new Dog(); //compile time type is Animal runtime type is Dog
Console.WriteLine(animal.GetType().Name); // Dog
...
animal = new Cat(); // compile time type is still Animal (c# is Type safe)
// but runtime type just changed to Cat;
Console.WriteLine(animal.GetType().Name); // Cat
```

Notice that all the while you are programming your Animal animal will not be "just an object". Being of (compile) type Animal bears great tiding - `bool IsAlive` property, `Breath()` method, and more. But when you write your code (i.e. compile time) your "animal" instance won't have a `Tail` (because not every animal has a tail). You can only access (with intellisense for example) things that you are sure it has (only Animal things). That's still saying a lot, but not as much as it's concrete subclasses. It's a very general thing, and that's a good thing.